# How to Find <body> all internal elements using Simple Php Dom?

Tags: php, arrays, dom, simpledom

We are looking to view and modify the particular element using Simple PHP DOM,

```
<?php     
    include('../../../../dom/simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://www.google.com');   

    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {           
        //something like that match with $string, if value found then the particular element edited by the <u>$string</u>.
        if(stristr($tag->innertext,$string)) {}    
    }

    echo $html ; 
?>
```

We want to get all HTML elements, in array. We have to check each element, and if one is matching with our data, then we moderate that particular element.

Comment: I guess all element you are looking for us ` <u>$string</u>`

Comment: `stristr($tag->innertext,$string` something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try the folloing to extract all `<ul> .. </ul>`

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.yahoo.com/');
foreach($html->find('ul') as $element)
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

Comment: we are finding UL elements, we have to get all of the tags (<div><p><ul><li> etc...) in body of the particular url. is there any other dom, who can do the same job ?

Comment: You can use `$element->outertex`

Comment: but that is only for <u> tag, we have to match it on each element like if body of the yahoo.com having more than 25 elements (<div><p><ul><li> etc...), then we have to match each element's innertext with our variable $string.